# Failure while connecting external harddrive

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hard-disk, manjaro, dmesg

I am trying to connect a seagate external drive to my PC that runs `Manjaro 5.15.16-1`.
However, it is not detected by the system. It is not listed in `/dev`, I can't view it with `fdisk -l`. But, I can see it through lsusb.

Here is my `dmesg` output when I plug my drive in.

```
[ 1298.309372] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 1298.464162] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab44, bcdDevice=48.85
[ 1298.464179] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1298.464185] usb 1-4: Product: Backup+ Hub
[ 1298.464190] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 1298.464194] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 01CB0037B432
[ 1298.465693] hub 1-4:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1298.466048] hub 1-4:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 1298.582970] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[ 1298.602988] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab45, bcdDevice=48.85
[ 1298.603011] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1298.603014] usb 2-4: Product: Backup+ Hub
[ 1298.603020] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 1298.603022] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 01CB0037B432
[ 1298.605760] hub 2-4:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1298.606064] hub 2-4:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 1299.539488] usb 1-4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 1301.095960] usb 2-4.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[ 1301.113319] usb 2-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab38, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1301.113338] usb 2-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 1301.113346] usb 2-4.1: Product: Backup+ Hub BK
[ 1301.113352] usb 2-4.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 1301.113357] usb 2-4.1: SerialNumber: NA9QY9SY
[ 1301.120343] scsi host2: uas
[ 1301.121106] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Backup+ Hub BK   D781 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1301.122043] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 1301.122365] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[ 1302.149335] .......................ready
[ 1324.443771] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 11721045167 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
```

The drive is not partitioned.

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: it should appear in result of `lsblk`. did the disk has a filesystem or logical volume set up ?

Comment: Suspicious: [ 1299.539488] usb 1-4-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Also try the ```sudo partprobe -s``` command.

Comment: In your dmesg output, there are two drives?  Or three?

Comment: The drive has 3 USB Hubs, one of ports on one of the hubs has a problem. If nothing's connected to that port, no problem. The drive also has an interface that looks like a SCSI disk. That 6TB disk is attached to your system as `/dev/sda`. Read `man gparted parted`.